# Regex to split url and text to make custom html content

Tags: javascript, regex

Input string:

```
Hello <http://test.com:8080/test/|test_url> end.
```

I need it like:

```
Hello <a src="http://test.com:8080/test/">test_url</a> end.
```

I have tried searching for url and text split, but not get proper solution.

Please anyone help me on this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see you’re using `|` as a delimiter without escaping the URL. This might create problems as URL can also hold the same character. If you’re sure that your URLs won’t have that character, you could use the following regex script:

```js
const rexp = /<(.*?)\|(.*?)>/g
const input = "Hello <http://test.com:8080/test/|test_url> end."
const output = input.replace(rexp, '<a href="$1">$2</a>')
console.log(output)
```

Comment: Plus one but better yet: `/<([^<>]+)\|([^<>]*)/g`

Comment: this is `<http://test.com:8080/test/|test_url>` string input and based on that I need to convert it to proper html. so I think your solution will work.